# Is there any way to return the current filename in FORTRAN 77

Tags: fortran, filenames, fortran77

I'm working on several versions of the same code in FORTRAN 77 and in every code I print the file name and version number, but after so many versions it has become tedious to have to change that line. I was wondering if there is a way for the code to return its own file name since the file name has the version number in it? The line I have now looks something like this,  `codevers='testfile_v009'` and `print *, 'Code Version: ', codevers`
The only problem with this is that I copy the previous version of the code and make changes to it as the new version but often forget to  update those lines in the code.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Rather than answering "no" (indeed F77 doesn't even have the concept of a file containing the program's code), I'll say instead: this seems like a job for your compiler/preprocessor or source control system.  If you give details on those someone may be able to give a (non-standard) way to do that.

Comment: Okay great! Thank you guys!

Comment: another option may be to be to name the executable in some consistent way, then you can use `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT` (arg 0) to get that name. (If you seriously are stuck with f77 your compiler should probably have `getarg`)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, one approach will be to use compiler preprocessors. For example, if you make `test_ver1.F90` (free format) or `test_ver1.F` (fixed format)

```
program main
    print *, "current file = ", __FILE__
    print *, "current line = ", __LINE__
end program
```

and compile it as

```
gfortran test_ver1.F90
./a.out
```

you will get

```
current file = test_ver1.F90
current line =            3
```

How to invoke a preprocessor depends on the compiler used, so please consult the manual. (For many compilers, the preprocessor will be invoked if the file name has a suffix like `.F90` and `.F`, or by using options like `-cpp` or `-fpp`.)

---

An application of this is to define a code-checking macro, for example

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define _assert_(x) if (.not.(x)) then; print*, "In ",__FILE__,", line ",__LINE__; stop "assertion failed: " // "x"; endif
#else
#define _assert_(x) if (.not.(x)) then; print*, "In ",__FILE__,", line ",__LINE__; stop "assertion failed: " // #x; endif
#endif
```

With this saved in `mymacro.inc`, the following program (`test_ver2.F90`)

```
#include "mymacro.inc"

program main
    integer :: x, y
    x = 7 ; y = 8
    _assert_( x == y )
end program main
```

gives

```
In test_ver2.F90, line            6
STOP assertion failed:  x == y
```

which is convenient for sanity check. (You can turn this off by defining a blank macro `#define _assert_(x)` so that the overhead becomes zero in production runs.)

Comment: I wouldn't put both on one line, macros can easily exceed the line length limit. you never now in which path the source code will be compiled. And in Fortran 77 the length limit is especially severe.

Comment: @VladimirF Is there any way to write a macro that does not use semicolon? If any, I would like to use it definitely.

Comment: Also, "assert" etc is just an example. If one wants to avoid longer lines, one can always write a similar subroutine. As for line length, we could use options to make it larger or unlimited (if such macros are really to be used), like "-ffixed-line-length-none". And it's 2016, and most compilers support the standards >= 90, which is valid even if the codes are written in F77 style (I guess this is a line that you always mention...)